# PDO Catch result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How does one catch/echo the insert results? I have a insertion statement that say that no errors occured but nothing is actually placed in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no output from an `INSERT` statement, other than the meta data about errors and warnings, retrievable with [errorCode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and [errorInfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

If you post your query and your table structure, it's more likely that someone can be of help.  It sounds like the problem is most likely with your query.

Comment: PDO will not accept 'PASSWORD($PASSWORD)' FOR THE VALUES SECTION

Answer (score 0):

PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows inserted or updated by a statement.